# Derivation about the clutter problem of Expectation Propagation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Recently I have read the book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Bishop, and I spent a lot of time deriving the result of the clutter problem for Expectation Propagation. But I don't know how to derive Eq.(10.217) and Eq.(10.218), as you can see in the picture:
[image]
I don't understand why variable $\rho_{n}$ suddenly apperas in Eq.(10.219). I have read a lot about EP algorithms on the Internet, such as (1),(2) and (3). But almost all of them just give these conclusions without explaining how to derive them. Can anyone help me?

(1) Introduction to Expectation Propagation

(2) Expectation Propagation for approximate Bayesian inference

(3) https://jmhldotorg.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/slidescharlesuniversityep2013.pdf

Comment: Please provide the necessary relevant materials, equations in the same question so that potential answerers don't need to get bothered to go to an external link.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reminder. I have edited my question again.

Comment: I know it will take a lot of time to answer this question, but I just want to ask if there are some references for the precise derivation of the formula used in the example of clutter problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found that the derivation of this problem is one of the after-class exercises in PRML, and I have found the corresponding answer in [1].
Everyone can find the details in **Problem 10.39 Solution**.

[1] https://github.com/zhengqigao/PRML-Solution-Manual

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.